# How to calculate the size of a row return by a database query in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, types, sizeof

I have a rudimentary application which uses a `System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader` and the `Read` method to step through individual rows returned by a query sent to a Redshift database.

I want to get a rough estimate of the size of the row as it relates to the amount of data physically sent over the network. With this information, I could calculate that `TotalRows * RowSizeInBytes = DataTransferSize`.

My thought was to retrieve the type of each column returned with `GetType()` then use `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf()` to get the actual size of the data and add it all together.

I have found that I could not call the `SizeOf` method on a `String` or on a `DateTime`. I get an error similar to the following:

```
System.ArgumentException: 'Type 'System.DateTime' cannot be marshaled as an unmanaged structure; no meaningful size or offset can be computed.'
```

I started to create an `if` block that would recognize a `String` type and use the `Length()` method on the `String` rather than the marshal method. But, this led me to wonder if this is the correct way to do this.

My code looks like this:

```
reader.Read()
For a = 0 To reader.FieldCount - 1
    Console.WriteLine(reader(a).GetType().ToString() + ": " + reader(a).ToString())
    If reader(a).GetType() = GetType(String) Then
        Console.WriteLine(reader(a).ToString().Length)
    Else
        Console.WriteLine(System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(reader(a).GetType()).ToString())
    End If
Next
```

Can someone provide guidance on the correct way to get the approximate size of the row, in bytes, sent over the wire? My gut tells me that data type mismatches between the underlying database, the operating system/driver, and the programming language makes the size of particular data types (sent over the wire), such as integers, somewhat ambiguous. I am less worried about this, but I would like a solution to consider this.

Comment: The data types returned are not managed types exactly, so you can't use this method to get the size of the data. For example you may have a float(24) in the database, but .NET doesn't have this type and it may use a single, which is 8 bits larger. Basically you are looking at the presentation layer but you are interested in the network or transport layer. I'm not aware of a way to do that with a .NET API

Comment: You could write a program to read a known number of rows from the database and use the "App history" tab in Task Manager to see how much network traffic that generated. Not very accurate, but with plenty of rows read it could give a reasonable approximation.